# How to stream the main stream of my dahua ip camera via http url

Tags: stream, ip-camera

Does any one know how i can see the main stream of my dahua ip camera via http url?
I tried this but not worked:
http://my_cam_ip/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?camera=[channel]

Answer (score 2):

Have you try using RTSP `rtsp://<username>:<password>@<ip>:<port>/cam/realmonitor?channel=<channelNo>&subtype=<typeNo>` ?

Comment: Even HTML5 doesn't support RTSP streams (unless the stream is transcoded before it hits the browser).  Hence asking for URL for a *HTTP* stream.
.
Frustrating thing is dahua camera and NVR web pages can each stream video to browsers without plugins/browser extensions, so there is obviously a way. 
.
Closest I got is " rtspoverwebsocket " and a "wsURL" that implies a WebSockets method -
wsURL: m.wsprotocol + "://" + m.ip + ":" + m.port + "/rtspoverwebsocket",
...but reverse engineering this is beyond me.
.
This git project might help?
https://github.com/TeamDotworld/dahua-rtsp-web